# In Python3.8, Cannot get a variable to be checked in an if statement

Tags: python

I am learning python.  I am not new to programming, so this is frustrating and a little embarrassing too:  I I want to check if the random number is 20 - and if it is, change the background color.  If I change comparison to  != it works.  But I cannot seem to check for a value.  I tried making the result a string/int as random generates a float.  Any ideas..?

The code follows:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

temp_result = 0
pickedColor = ""


def d20roll():

    temp_result = random.randint(1, 20) # generates a float
    lbl_result["text"] = str(temp_result) # makes the float a string for display

    print(temp_result)  #shows me the result

if temp_result == 20:# if the rnd is 20, make the color red.
    pickedColor = "red"
else:
    pickedColor = "black"

window = tk.Tk()
window.columnconfigure(0, minsize=150)
window.rowconfigure([0, 1], minsize=50)
frame = tk.Frame(
    master=window,
    relief=tk.RAISED,
    borderwidth=2)

frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2,pady=2)
btn_d20roll = tk.Button(master=frame, text="D20 Roll", command=d20roll)
lbl_result = tk.Label(fg="white", bg=pickedColor)

btn_d20roll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
lbl_result.grid(row=1, column=0)


window.mainloop() '''
```

Comment: [`randint` returns an integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint). Isn't that check supposed to go into the function above it?

Comment: to test it try `temp_result = 20`, it should work.

Comment: You need to call `d20roll()` before the `if` line otherwise temp_result is __always__ `0` - because it hasn’t been modified. BTW you should really not use globals like `d20roll()` modifying `temp_result` - make `d20roll()` return the random value and assign that using e.g. `temp_result = d20roll()`

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of temp_result inside a function, and testing that value outside of that function. Without diving too far in your code, I see 2 problems with that:

- At the moment you test the value of temp_result, the function has not been called yet. The value of temp_result is therefore still the initial value.
- When you assign to a variable inside of a function, Python considers that variable local to the function and no change will be visible outside of the function. You could change that by using `global temp_result` in the function, but it's generally not recommended to communicate values from inside a function to outside of it. It's better to return a value instead.

You're going to have to arrange your code so that a button press will result in:

- a random number being generated
- that random number being compared to some value
- and the background color being set to some value based on that

I'm not familiar with Tkinter so I can't really help with that.